# Can I profile NodeJS Applications using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, performance, profiling

I can successfully connect the VS Code debugger to my remote NodeJS target using the Chrome protocol. I believe that same protocol supports profiling and performance measurements as it is easy to do from Chrome Dev Tools, but I am not sure it is something I can do from VS Code directly.

Is there any support for this feature ? How can I use it ?

Comment: VSCode goal is to be a text editor, not an IDE. However you can develop an extension that do that (probably there are some already)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Visual Studio Code 1.45 (April 2020) should help, as it integrates [Javascript debugging capabilities](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/a21fa6fa94d2e319ba48e3b6fe1e5067fb5ce35a/release-notes/v1_45.md#new-javascript-debugger), including profiling:

> ### New JavaScript debugger
>
> This month we've continued making progress on our new JavaScript debugger.
> It's installed by default on Insiders, and can be installed [from the Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly) in VS Code Stable.
>
> You can start using it with your existing launch configurations by enabling the **`debug.javascript.usePreview`** setting.
>
> Here are some new features added this month:
>
> #### Profiling Support
>
> You can capture CPU profiles from your Node.js or browser applications by clicking the new "Profile" button in the Call Stack view, or using the **`Debug: Take Performance Profile`** command.
>
> Once you do, you can choose how long the profile will run: until you stop it, for a length of time, or until you hit another breakpoint.
>
> After the profile ends, it's saved in your workspace folder and visualized in VS Code.
> When you open the profile, code lenses are added to your files containing performance information at a function level and for certain 'hot' lines.
> Unlike profiles captured in many other tools, the recorded profile is sourcemap-aware.

[image: JS Debug profiling]

---

[cheesus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377011/cheesus) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794597/can-i-profile-nodejs-applications-using-visual-studio-code/61585758?noredirect=1#comment111017101_61585758) having a problem with the line numbers in the profiler output.
Hence, [`microsoft/vscode-js-debug` issue 559](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/559#issuecomment-656310782):

> Turns out this is because that location is inside a function that only exists in the compiled code.
> We actually do try to source-map it back into the original file, but there's no mapping at that location to use.
>
> [image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/24b6e6f18cade2b5c8a621ded5241dc752896d00/68747470733a2f2f6d656d65732e706565742e696f2f696d672f32302d30372d38376265353862372d343530622d346334322d613233302d3266306532376336356234322e706e67]
>
> If you change your target to `es6` or newer -- which you can do nowadays unless you're targeting Internet Explorer or Node versions <= 4 -- TS does not need to generate this stuff and line numbers work.
> Your code will also run faster. Here's the latest mappings
>
> This debugger only supports Node 8 and above.
> Due to the fact that this bug is only present when targeting old JavaScript versions when using in-place transpilation on code compiled for a version of Node older than what the debugger itself supports, and the complexity involved in fixing this, I will close this issue as out-of-scope.

Comment: Could have posted a comment and I would have updated the answer. OP downvoted and removed accepted answer before saw this change (which as you note is April 2020)

Comment: @adamrights I am sorry for the downvote, that was not warranted indeed.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the hint. However, the line numbers in the profiler output are wrong. Since I have many anonymous methods, most of them don't appear with a name, and so the profiler output is mostly useless for me. Do you get accurate line numbers?

Comment: @cheesus I do not indeed. Maybe there is an issue already opened on that particular bug?

Comment: I filed a bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/559. Turns out, the reason (in my case) was ts-node with target `es5`. With `es6`, the line numbers are correct.

Comment: @cheesus Thank you. Great feedback. I have included your comment and issue in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 16):

There is no plugin/support that I am aware of for initiating the profiling, or heap dumps, etc that are available in Chrome's Dev Tools. But, the VS Code debugger can work alongside the dev tools debugger.

Start from VS Code, and start debugging as you would. Then open dev tools from any tab in the Chrome/Chromium browser, and look for the green icon indicating a node.js debugging process is running (`manually done via node --inspect`):

[image].

Click this green icon and you'll have many of the browser dev tools features for debugging the node.js process, specifically the `memory` and `profiler` tabs.

Comment: This would force me to use a chrome/chromium browser, which can be quite a condition on some systems. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: Well, you can run commands to write memory data, etc that dev tools is hooking into, and then write that to file, and analyze it in some other toolset that you'd probably have to write a bit of a transformer too. So possible, but not nearly as plug and go.

Comment: Don't see the green NodeJS icon. The two buttons to the left are there ("Select an element" and "Toggle device bar"), but no green button. Chrome `87.0.4280.88`. Do I need an extension?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, There are many ways.

go to `package.json` and set:

```
  { 
    \\ other information 

    "scripts": {
      "debug": "node --inspect-brk" 
    } 
  }
```

after, run use command: `npm run debug yourFile.js`

or
you can execute in oneline `node --inspect-brk yourFile.js`

after this:
open chrome and go `chrome://inspect`

wait for a few seconds, to appears a remote target and click `inspect`

[image]

you can use `debbuger;` in your code to make a breakpoint.

To learn more go to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html).

In alternative you can use a plugin for `VS code`  ['Debugger for Chrome'](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) and follow the [guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it worth mentioning here that you can profile nodejs app using plain `console.profile` and `console.profileEnd`. It will generate .cpuprofile file in the project root folder which you can open then with VSCode. E.g. I used it to profile Mocha tests.

[image]

Comment: How do capture heap profile with it?

Comment: @user2734550 console.profile is for cpu profiling. There are different types of profiling. You can find more details on VSCode documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/profiling