# Performance profiling Node.js/TS with Visual Studio Pro 2019

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio, performance, profiling

I created a project in Visual Studio Pro 2019 from an existing Node.js TypeScript web code via the “Create a new project” wizard in VS. I am using a Windows 10 machine.

When I launch the Performance Profiler, the only available tool is “Events Viewer”. The tool that I want to use is “Instrumentation” so that I can measure call counts and call response times.

Has anyone had any success in doing this for a Node.js TypeScript web project in VS? If so, how were you able to get the “Instrumentation” tool enabled?

I have seen mention of profiling in the following link, but it is probably referring to Node.js JavaScript projects: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/node-js/

Comment: Forgot to mention the project contains tsconfig.json files and not jsconfig.json files since it is a Node.js TypeScript project and not a Node.js JavaScript project.

Comment: Before you ask, I already have Node.js Tools, Node.js development workload installed.

Comment: I am currently using VS Pro 2019 v16.7.2, but the I had the same issue with v16.6.2.

Comment: Profiling is mentioned here but I don't find any reference to it at documentation.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/node-js/

Perhaps I should profile with VS Code instead...

Comment: That page shows function/method performance profiling of Node.js with Visual Studio, but it does not list what edition of Visual Studio (Community/Code, Pro, Enterprise.) I have done function/method performance profiling of C# applications with VS Pro 2013. Given that and 2019 still being current, the non-listing of the VS edition on that page would imply they are saying VS Pro 2019 can do it.

Comment: I got Visual Studio pro 2019 and I have c++ project on same solution and that works fine. I ended up installing Visual Studio Code for profiling my Node.js project.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to profile Node.js project with Visual Studio 2019 but I'm using Visual Studio Code as a workaround.

[Can I profile NodeJS Applications using Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794597/can-i-profile-nodejs-applications-using-visual-studio-code)

I have been using profiler for C++ project with Visual Studio 2019 and it is better than profiler on VS Code.

Comment: In your profiling of Node.js with VS Code, have you been able to capture the response times of the functions/methods? Is your source code JavaScript or TypeScript? Were you using VS Code 2019?

Comment: I have 1.48.2 version of VS Code. My source is JavaScript. I can see execution times of methods but not nearly as high level of visualization, what I get for C++ with Visual Studio 2019 or for Android with Android Studio. But it's better than nothing.